# change preferred Wifi SSID in tasmota 11

Tags: smart-home, tasmota

I have a device with Tasmota 11.1.0 with two SSIDs configured. The device is now connecting to SSID2 and I would like it takes SSID1 as default one.
When I replace SSID2 with a non-existing name, then tasmota switches to SSID1 without problem.
I can't find any command to switch to SSID1 and set it as default.
I tried in command line: ssid1 but it does nothing. Also WifiConfig.

The documentation is not clear to me

```
Ssid<x>     <x> = 1..2
<value> = set AP<x> Wi-Fi SSID and restart
1 = reset AP<x> Wi-Fi SSID to firmware default (STA_SSID1 or STA_SSID2) and restart
SSID are limited to 32 characters. Do not use special characters or white spaces in the SSID
```

How to setup default (preferred) SSID on Tasmota so when both are working desired one is used?

Answer (score 2):

you may use below code on tasmota console, when you restart your Tasmota device it will try to connect SSID1

```
Backlog SSID1 <myssid>; Password1 <mypassword>; SSID2 <myssid2>; Password2 <mypassword2>
```